# Yii2: Proper way of writting the form's action

Tags: php, yii2

I have written form tag of YII2 specific as

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'builder/saveform','options' => ['method' => 'post']]) ?>
```

but when i run this, my external javascript is catching an error showing

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #builder/saveform
```

What is the error

Answer (score 17):

To change default action add it as the first argument in this format `['<controller>/<action>']`

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => ['builder/saveform'],'options' => ['method' => 'post']]) ?>
```

[Example from the Yii2 guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$method-detail)

Also, keep in mind that the method defaults to post, so specifying that is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'], 'action' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['site/signup'])]);
```

You can also use this snippet for custom form action and other attributes. createUrl method will not affect your url pattern.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

for the sake now i have written the following code

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => 'index.php?r=builder/saveform','options' => ['method' => 'post']]) ?>
```

it is working but is it the proper way to write???

Comment: You should use a route : `'action' => ['builder/saveform']`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by adding the action into the options like so

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-form', 'options' => ['method' => 'post', 'action' => 'site/add']]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Yii2

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
                            'id'      => 'login-form',
                            'options'=>['autocomplete'=>'off','method' => 'post', ],
                            'action' => '/frontend/web/user-management/auth/login',
                            'validateOnBlur'=>false,
                            'fieldConfig' => [
                                    'template'=>"{input}\n{error}",
                            ],
                                        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is still no accepted answer, the exact answer to your question is in the Error:
"unrecognized expression: '#builder/saveform' ". You have your 'id' [HTML tag](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-widget.html#$id-detail) of the Form being assigned a value of 'builder/saveform', which contains "/" - an illegal character in terms of [HTML4 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id). I suppose Yii has a "validation" in place resulting in your error.

Now, I believe you are trying to specify the relative URL for the Form submission. For that, please refer to Michael St Clair's answer.